# Unable to use int array item in table cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am trying to use int array element in tablecell item and it doesn't allow me to add.

**Code:**

I'm getting datatable column values into array

```
int[] price = dtPrice.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n[0])).ToArray();
```

Then using foreach I am adding the items to the cell text and its not working.

```
foreach(var item in price)
 {
    string strValue = e.Row.Cells[item].Text;
 }
```

Below error is what I see. Please provide any suggestions on how this can be handled.

[image]

Comment: How many prices do you have? And in how many cells do you want to store these prices? One for each cell in different rows of the grid or the sum of all prices in a single cell?

Comment: @Steve - I have three prices.

Comment: So you need three cells in three different rows or three cells in the same row or just the sum in a single cell?

Comment: @Steve - three cells in three different rows.

Comment: So your loop needs to use the Rows collection (foreach row in grid.Rows) and choose the index of the column (0,1,2 etc...) to identify a single cell and put there the value of the first, then second and third element of the price's array